# Modify RewriteContext Host in NetCore 2 rewriting middleware

Tags: url-rewriting, asp.net-core-2.0, middleware

I need to rewrite not redirect certain requests to GET files to an external storage location (hosted on a different domain)

I am able to accomplish this with redirecting using rewriter middleware, however i would like to rewrite instead.

I need to use some logic to rewrite to a specific file location, so I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x#method-based-rule tutorial.

When i set the  Host and path i can see the absolute url looks correct but when the method exits i get "No webpage was found for the web address:" and url displayed is the original request Url

RewriteRule.cs (also holds redirect url logic in ApplyRule() that i don't want to use)

```cs
public static void RewriteStorageFileRequests(RewriteContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        var path = request.Path.Value;
        if (path.Contains("foo/bar"))
        {
            context.Result = RuleResult.SkipRemainingRules;
            request.Host = new HostString("storage/space"); 
            request.Path = path.Replace("foo/bar", string.Empty);
            var test2 = request.GetDisplayUrl();
        }
    }
```

So essentially, if a call comes in as:

```html
https://localhost:44327/foo/bar/bf34d911-03db-5tda-9c99-c7dd96593159/w3.jpg
```

I want to rewrite it to:

```html
https://storage/space/bf34d911-03db-5tda-9c99-c7dd96593159/w3.jpg
```

Startup.cs

```cs
            app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().Add(RewriteUrlRule.RewriteStorageFileRequests));
```

test2 displays the correct url in the debugger.

I tried setting host to empty string and passing host value (storage/space) in path but still no luck.

[Before Rewriter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTHnj.png)

[After Rewrite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk9sb.png)

UPDATE: I was able to get rewrite to work by changing

```cs
context.Result = RuleResult.SkipRemainingRules;
```

to

```cs
context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
```

However, when i get to the Url it returns 200OK but does not show the image.
(see attached file)

So, right now the only way i can get images is still with Redirect

[Rewrite GET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiIaM.png)

Comment: So you would like to keep the url in browser `/localhost:44327/foo/bar` but return the recourse of different domain? It seems that URL rewrite only works if you redirect within the same site / web app apparently.See [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2011/08/24/return-404-4-not-found-when-url-rewrite/)

Comment: @XingZou Well, i want the rewrite with the new host (e.g my current host is 
    /localhost:44327, 
and i want to modify that to be
   /storage/space
)
So the final Url should be 
    https://storage/space/foo/bar
i got it to rewrite actually but it doesn't show the images, will post update

Comment: To get the ReWrite to work correctly, do you have to set the location header and a new status code? I notice you have not done that? What if you want to redirect to different server?